# Ruby on Rails Active Record Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

Employers and Jobs. Employers have many jobs. Jobs have a boolean field started.

I am trying to query and find a count for Employers that have more than one job that is started.

How do I do this?

Employer.first.jobs.where(started: true).count

Do I use a loop with a counter or is there a way I can do it with a query?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you imprive the title for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have condition on join

```
Employer.joins(:jobs).where(jobs: {started: true}).count
```

Comment: I tried this too, it's also giving the count for the total jobs that are started for some reason. ie. same result as Job.where(start: true).count. Any idea why?

Comment: are you sure that you have more than one job assigned to one employee?

Comment: yup. i have 4 employers. so Employer.joins(:jobs).count should be 4 right? but it's actually giving me the number of jobs. I'm confused

Comment: This is a great answer, especially since it can easily become a scope `:with_active_jobs`. I always find it best to use scopes or such before making custom methods. Rails has the power

Answer (score 1):

You could create a scope like this in your `Employer` model:

```
def self.with_started_job
  joins(:jobs)
    .where(jobs: { started: true })
    .having('COUNT(jobs.id) > 0')
end
```

Then, to get the number of employers that have a started job, you can just use `Employer.with_started_job.count`.

Comment: I tried this, it's giving the count for the total jobs that are started for some reason. ie. same result as Job.where(start: true).count. I copied your code into the model already. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

What is missing is a group by clause. Use `.group()` then `count`. Something like

```
Employer.select("employers.id,count(*)").joins(:jobs).where("jobs.started = 1").group("employers.id")
```

The query joins both tables, eliminates the records that are false, then it counts the total records for each employer.id when grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

#### Time for exploratory programming!

Given I don't know SQL really well, my way of doing this may not be optimal. I've been unable to use two aggregations without using a subquery. So I split the task in two:

- Fetch all employers who have more than one job started
- Count the number of entries in the result set

All on the database level, of course! And without raw SQL, so using Arel here and there. Here's what I've come up with:

```
class Employer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs

  # I explored my possibilities using this method: fetches
  # all the employers and number of jobs each has started.
  # Looks best> Employer.with_started_job_counts.map(&:attributes)
  # In the final method this one is not used, it's just handy.
  def self.with_started_job_counts
    jobs = Job.arel_table
    joins(:jobs).select(arel_table[Arel.star],
                        jobs[:id].count.as('job_count'))
      .merge(Job.where(started: true))
      .group(:id)
  end

  # Alright. Now try to apply it. Seems to work alright.
  def self.busy
    jobs = Job.arel_table

    joins(:jobs).merge(Job.where(started: true))
                .group(:id)
                .having(jobs[:id].count.gt 1)
  end

  # This is one of the tricks I've learned while fiddling
  # with Arel. Counts any relations on the database level.
  def self.generic_count(subquery)
    from(subquery).count
  end

  # So now... we get this.
  def self.busy_count
    generic_count(busy)
  end
  # ...and it seems to get what we need!
end
```

Resulting SQL is...large. Not huge, but you may have to solve performance issues with it.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT "employers".*
  FROM "employers"
    INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."employer_id" = "employers"."id"
  WHERE "jobs"."started" = ?
  GROUP BY "employers"."id"
  HAVING COUNT("jobs"."id") > 1
) subquery  [["started", "t"]]
```

...still, it does seem to get the result.